# Loading project from domain with unverified ceritificate

Tags: support, jobs

I'm trying to load a project in my SO career resume from a custom [GitLab repository](https://git.1adw.com/eaze/lib). Unfortunately, there is a problem with the certificate for this domain and I get an error `Sorry, we could not retrieve that URL for some reason.` Is there any opportunity to load this project?

Comment: Move the project to any of the common free repositories?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not an active contributor to this project anymore so I feel it won't be correct if I move it somewhere. Probably I should ask it to do this other maintainers.

Comment: True. Anyway, As Alex said in his answer, no way to show such project in your Careers profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to fix the certificate error, or provide us with a non-HTTPS version of that URL.

Even if we were to ignore the error, any employer looking at your profile would get a big browser warning anyway if they visited the link. So you really want to fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an employee of this company anymore so it will be very hard for me to make something for fixing it.